# mySQL innoDB - MATCH () ... AGAINST does not deliver expected results

Tags: mysql, pdo, full-text-search

In an `innoDB` I use below statement to search for keywords. The tables `company` and `note` are `Fulltext` indexed. While there is only one row with `Abraham Lincoln LTD` in the DB and I search for `Abraham` I do not get any kind of result. In fact I do not get any results from the fulltext indexed tables. What did I do wrong here ? mySQL Server version is : 5.7.13

```
$query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT 
                                    clients.id, 
                                    clients.num, 
                                    clients.company, 
                                    countries.en as country, 
                                    clients.country_id , 
                                    clients.city, 
                                    clients.mail, 
                                    clients.note 
                                    FROM clients, countries 
                                    WHERE clients.country_id=countries.id 
                                    AND (   MATCH (clients.company) AGAINST (:keyword) 
                                        OR  MATCH (clients.note)    AGAINST (:keyword)
                                        OR (countries.en=:keyword) 
                                        OR (clients.client_num=:keyword) 
                                        OR (clients.city=:keyword) 
                                        OR (clients.email=:keyword)  ) ');
```

EDIT :

After not getting a useful answer I tried myself to find another way. So I use this code now :

```
 $query = $this->db_con->prepare('
                                (SELECT 
                                clients.ID, 
                                clients.num, 
                                clients.company, 
                                countries.en as country, 
                                clients.country_id , 
                                clients.city, 
                                clients.email_1, 
                                clients.note 
                                FROM clients, countries 
                                WHERE clients.country_id=countries.ID 
                                AND ( MATCH (clients.company) AGAINST (:keyword)
                                OR      MATCH (clients.note)    AGAINST (:keyword)  )  )
                                UNION
                                (SELECT 
                                clients.ID, 
                                clients.num, 
                                clients.company, 
                                countries.de as country, 
                                clients.country_id , 
                                clients.city, 
                                clients.email_1, 
                                clients.note 
                                FROM clients, countries 
                                WHERE clients.country_id=countries.ID 
                                AND ( (countries.en     =:keyword)
                                OR    (clients.city     =:keyword)  
                                OR    (clients.num      =:keyword)  
                                OR    (clients.email_1  =:keyword) )    )
                              ');
```

It works as espected. I can search in fulltext inexed tables and others in one call (statement).

But it looks a bit complicated for me and time consumpting for the DB, so my question is if there is a more simple way to quick results ?
The current DB has 2.500 clients with 25 col. only. The DB will not grow beyond 10.000 clients in the next 5 years.

Comment: Did you commit your changes to your database? Fulltext indexes are only updated after a commit. Does your `join`-condition `clients.country_id=countries.id` give any results? (e.g: What happens if you remove the whole `AND`-part?) Did you actually bind your parameter? (You didn't add that part of your code)

Comment: How to commit fulltext indexes ? The join part works good.

Comment: EDIT : When I remove the whole AND () Part the join `clients.country_id=countries.id` works good. To each client its country is assigned (as far as I can assign it with thousand of clients ;-)